# How to show values in minor tickers in Bokeh 1.1.0

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I want to add labels on minor tickers in Bokeh (1.1.0), Would you please guide me how to do that ?
here is the image attached
[image: here is the image attached.]

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to add labels to the minor ticks. But you can increase the number of the major ticks:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.plotting import show

p = figure()
p.line([0, 20], [0, 20])

# The default value is 6.
p.xaxis.ticker.desired_num_ticks = 12

show(p)
```